# Pandas Dataframe - faster apply?

Tags: optimization, pandas, dataframe, apply

I've got the following code:

```
from dateutil import parser
df.local_time = df.local_time.apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))
```

It seems to be taking prohibitively long time. How can I make it faster?

Comment: How about `to_datetime`?

Comment: You should avoid `apply` and use `to_datetime`: `df['local_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local_time'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `pd.to_datetime` for faster datetime conversion. For example, imagine you have this data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        dates = pd.date_range('2015', freq='min', periods=1000)
        dates = [d.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S') for d in dates]
        dates[:5]
Out[1]:
['01 Jan 2015 00:00:00',
 '01 Jan 2015 00:01:00',
 '01 Jan 2015 00:02:00',
 '01 Jan 2015 00:03:00',
 '01 Jan 2015 00:04:00']
```

You can get datetime objects this way:

```
In [2]: pd.to_datetime(dates[:5])
Out[2]:
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:02:00', '2015-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

But this still can be slow in some cases. To be *really* fast on converting dates from strings where you know that all dates have the same format, you can specify the `format` argument (e.g. here, `format='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'`) or more automatically, use `infer_datetime_format=True` so that the format will be inferred only once and used on the rest of the entries. This can result in some great speedups as the size of the array grows (but only works if all formats are consistent!).

For example, on these 1000 string dates I defined above:

```
from dateutil import parser
ser = pd.Series(dates)

%timeit ser.apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))
10 loops, best of 3: 91.1 ms per loop

%timeit pd.to_datetime(dates)
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop

%timeit pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
100 loops, best of 3: 5.96 ms per loop

%timeit pd.to_datetime(dates, infer_datetime_format=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.79 ms per loop
```

We get about a factor of 20 speedup by specifying or inferring the datetime format in `pd.to_datetime()`.